# Looping over Ragged Tensors in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I wondered if there was any way too loop over Ragged Tensors, similarly to tf.map_fn. My Ragged Tensor has a different amount of rows but contains 4 points which I would like to retrieve.

The input looks as follows:

```
ragged_tensor[0] equals (100, 4)
ragged_tensor[1] equals (50, 4)
```

For now I can retrieve all of the points by looping over the first tensor inside the RaggedTensor:

```
test = tf.map_fn(lambda box: tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(img, box[0], box[1], box[2], box[3]), tf.cast(boxes, tf.int32), dtype=tf.float32)
```

Does anyone have any experience with this, or might give me some tips&tricks? All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to get the whole array of points:

```
points = tf.reshape(ragged_tensor.flat_values, [-1, 4])
```